# Why don't configuration properties appear in visual studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, properties, c++-cli, project

I've just installed Visual Studio 2012, targeting C++ and C++-CLI applications on our build server (a 64-bit Windows-7 platform) but for some reason, when I right-click on a project I can't see any `Configuration Properties`.

This isn't confined to existing projects either; When I create a simple console application (doesn't matter whether it's a clr or wind32 application) I get the same issue.

[image]

Is there something missing from this system?

**Edit** - Not sure if this is connected but when I try and create a CLR Console Application I get two error boxes pop up. The first says 'null' is null or not an object and the next says `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException`.

Comment: Are you trying to say "Configuration Manager" ? It's available under the Build menu on the main menubar.

Comment: No; if you right-click on a project and select `Properties` I would expect to see `Common Properties` and `Configuration Properties` root items in the tree on the left of the property pages. For some reason I'm only seeing `Framework and References` in the left hand panel though.

Comment: I've been using VS2012 for more than a year actively and I don't know what are you talking about. My left panel always looked like this:
http://95.211.218.159/vs2012.jpg

Comment: Yours is a vb.net project. Mine are `C++` or `C++/CLI` which is why they look different. I'll add that as a tag and mention it in the question just to make it clear.

Comment: Well, that install did not go well.  Stuff is missing, usually, when it falls over like this.  Typically induced by having VS installed on the machine previously and not cleaning it up properly.  Short from re-imaging the machine to get rid of the junk in the registry, an attempt worth trying is to run setup.exe with the /uninstall /force options.

Comment: Could this be because we had Microsoft Build Tools 2013 installed before Visual Studio?